# Aligning table within latex editor

Tags: texstudio, code, resources

Suppose I have the following table in my TeXstudio editor:

```
    Latex & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & 101.86 & 64.60 & 127.20  \\ 
    Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.59 & -7.24 & -49.00 & 22.00  \\ 
    Cons & 360 & -17.19 & 23.4 & -17.22 & -79.00 & 43.00 \\ 
    Apple and Orange & 360 & 3.38 & 13.84 & 3.60 & -47.00 & 29.00   \\ 
    Services and Harry  & 104 & -4.96 & 20.8 & -4.81 & -57.00 & 30.00   \\ 
    Manchester & 360 & -9.29 & 8.64 & -9.26 & -35.00 & 8.00 \\
```

Sometimes I want to change some numbers in the table. However, it is really really hard to keep tracking which number is behind the other in the table. Is there is any way to align the `&` behind each other?

Comment: I set the default font in my editor to a fixed-width (ttstyle) font, and then, when creating .tex files, I insert spaces as needed during the original text input to achieve whatever editing alignments I wish.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes M I know which editor do you use? Could not find (ttstyle) font in TexStudio.

Comment: I say "ttstyle" merely to indicate a font with constant width (the name will vary with the font itself).  In the TeXworks editor, for example, I use "Lucida Console" font.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin Go to Options > Configure TeXstudio > Editor > Font Family. There you can select a fixed-width font. Next to the font dropdown menu is also a "Show Only Monospaced Fonts" checkbox which hides all non-fixed-width fonts from the dropdown menu. Under LaTeX > Manipulate Tables exists a command to “Align Columns” (it is also in the button row at the top of the window). This needs a `tabular` environment (I guess `tabularx` works, too) and even checks for column specifications.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It worked well with `tabular` and a little messy with `tabularx`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `latexindent`! You can find it here: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

If I have a `main.tex` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{%
l
S[table-format=3.0]
S[table-format=3.2]
S[table-format=2.2]
S[table-format=3.2]
S[table-format=-2.2]
S[table-format=3.2]
}
Latex & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & 101.86 & 64.60 & 127.20  \\ 
Manufacturing & 360 & -7.33 & 12.59 & -7.24 & -49.00 & 22.00  \\ 
Cons & 360 & -17.19 & 23.4 & -17.22 & -79.00 & 43.00 \\ 
Apple and Orange & 360 & 3.38 & 13.84 & 3.60 & -47.00 & 29.00   \\ 
Services and Harry  & 104 & -4.96 & 20.8 & -4.81 & -57.00 & 30.00   \\ 
Manchester & 360 & -9.29 & 8.64 & -9.26 & -35.00 & 8.00 \\ 
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

and run

```
latexindent -w main.tex
```

I get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{%
        l
        S[table-format=3.0]
        S[table-format=3.2]
        S[table-format=2.2]
        S[table-format=3.2]
        S[table-format=-2.2]
        S[table-format=3.2]
        }
        Latex              & 360 & 101.77 & 10.71 & 101.86 & 64.60  & 127.20 \\ 
        Manufacturing      & 360 & -7.33  & 12.59 & -7.24  & -49.00 & 22.00  \\ 
        Cons               & 360 & -17.19 & 23.4  & -17.22 & -79.00 & 43.00  \\ 
        Apple and Orange   & 360 & 3.38   & 13.84 & 3.60   & -47.00 & 29.00  \\ 
        Services and Harry & 104 & -4.96  & 20.8  & -4.81  & -57.00 & 30.00  \\ 
        Manchester         & 360 & -9.29  & 8.64  & -9.26  & -35.00 & 8.00   \\ 
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

in a second.

Please read the manual before, as this is overwriting your input file. The tool gets even nicer in combination with `arara`. For example:

```
% arara: indent: {overwrite: yes; trace=true}
```

Comment: `latexindent` is included in both TeX Live and MikTeX, so it's not necessary to get it from GitHub.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh cool. Thanks for the update.

Comment: That an awesome solution. I have tested it on windows, is there any other equivalent way to do it on mac.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin Glad I could help. I have no idea about Mac. Should be the same actually. Install Perl and get the script via you TeX-distribtution. Maybe the manual of `latexindent` contains some information about Mac. You will have to look at it.

Comment: If it's on OS X, you should be able to just use it. OS X comes with perl, but my texlive (2013) doesn't have latexindent so I can't test it. (I'm waiting for texlive 2015 before I upgrade.) Assuming you have texlive 2014, look for it from the Terminal command line with `mdfind -name latexindent.pl`, then use it with `perl <full-path-to-latexindent.pl> <documentname.tex>`.

Comment: awesome, thanks for advertising `latexindent`, it brings a smile to my face :)

Comment: @cmhughes haha, your delight made me smile, too. But I am sorry to have left an issue on your repository... The second last line got one tab too much, imho.

Comment: no worries, all bug reports gratefully received :)

Comment: @alexis I found it using `mdfind` like you mentioned. I just had to install `YAML::Tiny` module to get it to work.

Answer (score 11):

In TexStudio you select the data in your table and go to (top of the screen)

LaTeX > Manipulate Tables > Align Columns

This will neatly align your table at the &'s.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it does reformat the table but with no proper alignment.

Comment: It does not work @Barre42

Answer (score 1):

The way I would handle this example is to insert enough white space in order to generate a table-like view in the editor. The white space is later ignored by latex. Accordingly, an alignment like the following example would be no problem.

```
Latex         & 360  & 101.77  & 10.71  & 101.86 & 64.60  & 127.20  \\ 
Manufacturing & 360  & -7.33   & 12.59  & -7.24  & -49.00 & 22.00   \\ 
Cons          & 360  & -17.19  & 23.4   & -17.22 & -79.00 & 43.00   \\
```

If you have very big tables you could also edit them in a spreadsheet and subsequently export as CSV-file with the `&` as delimiter.

Comment: Well, that is what I am doing at the moment. However, it is only suitable for small tables like the one in the question (the smallest table in my document). For big tables with different contents' width, this would be a nightmare.