# How to create a TeXstudio macro to apply "Align Columns" for all matrices I want

Tags: matrices, texstudio, search

### How to create a TeXstudio macro to apply "Align Columns" for all matrices I want

After learning about about the command `Align Columns` I immediately fell in love with it and created a shortcut (`Ctrl + Alt + T` == `Alt Gr + T`) to use it in a blink of an eye. So far so good.

Recently I learned I could execute commands with TeXstudio's macros and not just use it to insert predefined text.

At this point I asked if it was possible to automatize the whole `Search` and `Align Columns` manual procedure.

I found the following infos about it:

- [automatic-code-alignment-with-texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389710/automatic-code-alignment-with-texstudio)
- [aligning-table-within-latex-editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248166/aligning-table-within-latex-editor/248171#248171)
- [emultiple-find-replace-in-texstudio-using-script-macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419781/multiple-find-replace-in-texstudio-using-script-macros)
- [texstudio/wiki/Scripts/](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/)
- [usermanual_en.html#SECTION33](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)

Unfortunately, I could not install `latexindent` so I must find a way around, and I don't know the syntax enough to create from scratch.

I searched for info and tried some but I have no idea how to perform something like `Align Columns` of any shortcut in the `MACRO` environment.

The idea is have something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a             &              b \\
    c             &           d
  \end{pmatrix}  \\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a             &        b \\
    c             &                 d
  \end{bmatrix}  \\
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    a             &                 b\\
    c             &            d
  \end{Bmatrix}   \\
  \begin{vmatrix}
    a             &       b \\
    c             &              d
  \end{vmatrix}  \\
  \begin{Vmatrix}
    a             &                  b \\
    c             &                  d
  \end{Vmatrix}  \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Apply the macro, which sketch I let below

```
%SCRIPT
options = "g"
scope = editor.document().cursor(0, 0, -1);
editor.find("matrix", options, scope, "");
//eval("AlignColumns");
//eval("Ctrl + Alt + T");
//editor.findNext();
```

[image]

and get the same result as manually go around using `Search` (`F3`) and `Align Columns` (`Alt Gr + T`) the whole document.

Adding `array`, `tabular`, `split`, and others environments that use `&` would also be something interesting.

[image]

Comment: Latexindent does this. If you find an alternative, let me know :) (author of latexindent)

Comment: @cmhughes, indeed, I tried to use latexindent, I saw your Youtube Video. `latexindent` does much more than just aligning tables and matrices, but I could not install Perl at the computer I use, therefore I asked for a specific workaround. Find a subset of word, apply the command. I don't know how to apply to command via macro.

Comment: If you're on Windows, there is a Windows executable available. You just need it and default settings.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very simple macro to work around

It took a while but I found out TeXstudio command `app.simulateKeyPress("<Keys>")`.

Combining the find I needed with the shortcut I'd already defined ("Ctrl+Alt+T"), I could emulate the same combinations I used manually into a single key combination due macro's shortcut.

```
%SCRIPT
editor.find("matrix", true, true, false, false);
app.simulateKeyPress("Ctrl+Alt+T");
//editor.findNext();
```

I must press the shortcut I chose (`Shift+F1`) twice, since I'm just looking for the word `matrix`.

I shall recognize this is not the most elegant solution, I just combined two tools.
Probably someone with more skills than me can come with a better solution searching in a list of words or some other trick I don't know.

[image]

Comment: @cmhughes, this answer was the best I could perform with my current knowledge.

Comment: Formatting code is tricky :)